# Бот не меняет сообщение Telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Есть такой код:

```
def accept(call):
try:

    message = call.message.text.split('\n')

    id_user = message[2].split(':')
    id_user = id_user[1].replace(' ', '')

    bot.send_message(id_user, '❤️ Ваша заявка *была принята*!', parse_mode="Markdown")
    database.user_update_merchant_id(id_user, 2)

    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=admin, message_id=call.message.message_id, text= f'❤️ Пользователь @{str(call.message.chat.username)} принят', parse_mode="Markdown")
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=support, message_id=call.message.message_id, text= f'❤️ Пользователь @{str(call.message.chat.username)} принят', parse_mode="Markdown")
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text=" Вы приняли пользователя")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

При нажатии кнопки принять админом или саппортом, человеку отправляется сообщение:

`bot.send_message(id_user, '❤️ Ваша заявка *была принята*!', parse_mode="Markdown")`

После чего сообщение с кнопкой принять должно меняться на

`bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=admin, message_id=call.message.message_id, text= f'❤️ Пользователь @{str(call.message.chat.username)} принят', parse_mode="Markdown")`

у админа все работает прекрасно сообщение меняется, но у саппорта ничего не меняется и выдается ошибка

```
A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message to edit not found
```

Кто знает что делать?
Так же хотелось бы узнать что делать чтобы вместо `@{str(call.message.chat.username)}` писался username человека которого приняли, а то там пишется username того кто принял.

Comment: хелп пажавуста помогити

Comment: Вероятно такая ошибка, из-за того, что нечего изменять, то есть такого `message_id` не существует у саппорта - у него на это действие, как я понимаю совсем другой `message_id`. Чтобы как-то это проверить - существуют разные дебаггеры, но проще будет print-ить `message_id` и смотреть результат. Не знаю, какие будут результаты, но предположу, что одним из решений,( но не самых лучших, я так как-то давно делал для своего проекта) будет запись `id` в базу, и изменение `edit_message`, указывая именно `id` из базы. Или придумайте другую логику для сохранения